# Multiple xml file processing on pyspark

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have multiple xml files around (15000) and we are using databricks notebook and pandas df to process multiple files in loop using XML tree. Each file takes around 1.67 sec which is like 6hrs for all files. Which is quite high for daily job.
Is there a better way to achieve good performance? Can PySpark df be faster compared to pandas Df? Also can combining all xml files in one big and then processing it with pandas be faster?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you
Avani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the steps below to improve performance:

1. Use High Concurrency clusters:

[image]

The key benefits of High Concurrency clusters are that they provide fine-grained sharing for maximum resource utilization and minimum query latencies.

2. Enable autoscaling.

All-Purpose cluster - On the Create Cluster page, select the Enable autoscaling checkbox in the Autopilot Options box:

[image]

3. Job cluster - On the Configure Cluster page, select the Enable autoscaling checkbox in the Autopilot Options box:

[image]

4. Configure the min and max workers.

[image]

When the cluster is running, the cluster detail page displays the number of allocated workers. You can compare the number of allocated workers with the worker configuration and adjust as needed.

Refer - https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#high-concurrency-clusters

---

**EDIT -**

> Can PySpark df be faster compared to pandas Df?

Pandas run operations on a single machine whereas PySpark runs on multiple machines. PySpark is a best fit which could processes operations many times(100x) faster than Pandas.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details with steps. We are using Azure data factory to orchestrate the databricks cluster. I only see option for autoscaling there with min and max workers. I will try updating that and see. Is there any way to optimize code?

Comment: @avanijain , Updated my answer. If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Comment: Thanks, totally makes sense. Thank you